# InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm running a Grails application in "PRODUCTION ENV." with version 2.3.1. It runs fine for some time. But after some time, it starts failing with exception "InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException". Again when I delete target folder and re run the application, it works good.

There is no error while working in "DEVELOPMENT ENV".

Detailed exception is

```
[[ErrorType:class org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException],
 [ErrorMessage:The given object has a null identifier: com.test.model.Test;
    nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException:
    The given object has a null identifier: com.test.model.Test]]
```

Comment: Are you using `run-app` in the prod environment for a live site? You should be building a war and deploying that to Tomcat or another servlet container.

Comment: “Yes we are doing this to test for the time being some stuff on prod mode. Eventually we will do it in a war. Are you saying that this issue is due to running from within grails and running with a war would resolve this issue?”

Comment: It could be. Pretty easy to test the theory :)